# Yii2 rest api надо взять ID пользователя

Tags: php, yii2, rest

Столкнулся с такой проблемой в **yii2 rest api**.
Создаю магазин. там есть корзина и есть 2 варианта оформления товара.
1 Пользователь не авторизован. Он должен ввести свои данные..
2. Пользователь авторизован.
в первом случае в контроллере CheckOrder нужно заносить все данные о пользователе, если же пользователь авторизован нужно взять ID.

Как взять ID если авторизован, а если нет добавлять его все данные в **REST API**?

> Делал так. не помогает

```
 public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
            'authMethods' => [
                HttpBasicAuth::className(),
                HttpBearerAuth::className(),
                QueryParamAuth::className(),
            ],
        ];
        $behaviors['access'] = [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
```

Метод

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        if(\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return ['msg' => 'GUEST'];
        } else {
            return \Yii::$app->user->identity->getId();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю на сколько это правильно

```
public static function getAuthTokenFromHeader()
{
    if(Yii::$app->request->getHeaders()->get('Authorization')){
        $authHeader = Yii::$app->request->getHeaders()->get('Authorization');
        preg_match('/^Bearer\s+(.*?)$/', $authHeader, $token);
        return $token[1];
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}

public static function findByToken($token)
{
    return static::findOne(['token' => $token]);
}

public static function getIdByToken()
{
    $user = self::findByToken(self::getAuthTokenFromHeader());

    if($user != null){
        return $user->id;
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не совсем то, что нужно(( Мне надо в **behaviors** сделать настройки для этого. А ваш код хорош, но получается что я логику Yii2 обхожу. если не ощибаюсь

Comment: Может это поможет... https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-authentication